# JAVA FX + Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, javafx

I have never worked with JavaFX but right now I need to write a small application that will have embed browser and I need to pass some data to browser and get some data back from browser.
As I have read I need to you JavaScript as a bridge for exchanging the data.
I have tried a lot of examples like this:

http://knowles.co.za/javafx-and-javascript-calling-java-from-javascript/

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/WebEngineLoadListener.htm

but I can't make anything work.

Can someone give me working example?

Comment: "I am unable to make anything work". Try a very simple example, and post the complete example here, explaining what you think it should do and what it does that is different. Simply saying something doesn't work isn't a sufficient description of a problem for anyone to help.

Comment: If you are looking for an implementation of JavaFX in JavaScript (TypeScript) then take a look at [Script4J](https://github.com/PavelKastornyy/script4j/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i think you are asking about **interaction between javaFX an JavaScript**

at first this operation is performed through **Nashorn** Engine

let's understand a simple example and write its complete code:

A problem: we want to get the sum of two number using javafx, JS, and html

suppose that we have HTML with

1. two input fields to take values from the user
2. button that calculate the sum of the numbers on the fields
3. div in which we preview the sum of the numbers

when user click on the button it calls a JavaScript function that calls a java method which(ie: java method) receives the two numbers and returns the sum

so let's create a java class that has a method that calculates the sum of two numbers, it's so simple

```
public class Adder{

public double getSum(String a, String b)
{
    return Double.parseDouble(b) + Double.parseDouble(a);
}}
```

so we need to pass(inject) a java object to the javascript so we can use it to call methods, so how to inject a java object into the JS?
simply use the following code

```
WebView browser = new WebView();
    browser.getEngine().getLoadWorker()
            .stateProperty()
            .addListener((obs, old, neww) ->
            {
                if (neww == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED)
                {
                    JSObject jsobj = (JSObject) browser.getEngine()
                            .executeScript("window");
                    jsobj.setMember("adder", new Adder());
                }
            });
```

we inject in the last line a java object(new Adder() ) and we give it a name(adder) to be used in the java script code, so the question now is how to use the adder in the JavaScript?

consider the following JavaScript function and call it add

```
function add()
        {
            var sum = adder.getSum("5", "7");
        }
```

as we see, it's very simply we just call the passed(injected) java object(Adder object) but the name adder and calls the method getSum("5","7")

now let's have a complete code

1- create a new JavaFX project in your IDE and named the main class NashornTest and  here's the code

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import netscape.javascript.JSObject;
public class NashornTest extends Application{

@Override

public void start(Stage stage)
{

    //create an embeded web browser
    WebView browser = new WebView();

    browser.getEngine().getLoadWorker()
            .stateProperty()
            .addListener((obs, old, neww) ->
            {
                if (neww == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED)
                {
                    // Let JavaScript make calls to adder object,
                    //so we need to inject an [Adder] object into the JS code
                    JSObject bridge = (JSObject) browser.getEngine()
                            .executeScript("window");
                    bridge.setMember("adder", new Adder());
                }
            });
    //load the html page
    browser.getEngine().load(NashornTest.class.getResource("index.xhtml").toString());
    VBox box = new VBox(browser);

    Scene scene = new Scene(box);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    launch(args);
}}
```

2-create a java class and called it Adder, and here's the code

```
public class Adder{

public double getSum(String a, String b)
{
    return Double.parseDouble(b) + Double.parseDouble(a);
}}
```

3-create an XHTML file and call it index.xhtml and here's the scripts, it must be in the same java package of the NashornTest.java

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <script>
            function add()
            {
                var num1 = document.getElementById("num1Field").value;
                var num2 = document.getElementById("num2Field").value;
                //make calls for injected java object
                var sum = adder.getSum(num1, num2);
                document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = "sum = " + sum;
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="num1Field"/>
        <input id="num2Field"/>
        <button onclick="add()">sum</button>
        <div id="outputDiv"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

at the end this is a simple start for interaction between Java and JavaScript, and i hope this post is helpful and useful

Comment: Thanks, amazing example. One more question -  how should I define adder.getSum(num1, num2) function from AngularJS? it says adder not defined.

Comment: sorry bro, i don't never deal with AngularJS ,

Comment: and i suggest you to mix normal js code when dealing with java
but i used javafx with JQuery and they worked fine

Comment: I changed document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = "sum = " + sum; to - alert(sum); and it is not working

Comment: because the JavaFX WebView doesn't support popup menus 
but i give you ability to listen to javascript popup actions via 
browser.getEngine().setOnAlert((javafx.scene.web.WebEvent<String> event) ->
        {
            System.out.println("listen 2 js alert()" + event.getData());
        });

Comment: This worked for me after I changed the extension from xhtml to html. Otherwise it just rendered the innertext.

Comment: I am not getting it in Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)